# I have this error " unable to locate package libuhd003"

Tags: 12.04

I want to use ettus device usrp n210 when I write the following command in terminal I have error "unable to locate package libuhd003 "

```
sudo apt-get install libuhd003
```

Comment: The package is only available from Ubuntu14.04 onwards. You need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The package is available since Trusty in the universe repositories.

1. Upgrade your system to Trusty

   ```
   sudo update-manager --proposed
   ```
2. Enable the universe repositories

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libuhd003
   ```

---

An other possibility, you could try to compile the package and the necessary dependencies in Precise.